# reshape dataframe from one single column to multiple columns

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
> tmp
  Genome value
1      a     1
2      b     2
3      c     3
4      a     3
5      b     3
6      c     2
```

I have tried to use dcast but is not doing what i want.
I want the dataframe below.

```
  a b c
1 1 2 3    
2 3 3 2 

> dput(tmp)
structure(list(Genome = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Using `tidyverse` , `tmp %>%
  group_by(Genome) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(Genome, value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R

```
unstack(df, value ~ Genome)

 a b c
1 1 2 3
2 3 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` (with simplifications from markus):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tmp)

tmpw <- tmp[, dcast(.SD, rowid(Genome) ~ Genome)][, !"Genome"]
tmpw

#    a b c
# 1: 1 2 3
# 2: 3 3 2
```

Or more concisely as pointed out by markus:

Base `R` alternative (can be modified if data is less regular):

```
data.frame(split(tmp$value, tmp$Genome))

#   a b c
# 1 1 2 3
# 2 3 3 2
```

Comment: Your first option could also be written as `dcast(setDT(tmp), rowid(Genome) ~ Genome)` (and deleting column `Genome` if needed)